# Why does December 8th, 2009 Patch Tuesday Kill IIS in Windows Server 2003?

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6, windows-update

We installed the updates from Microsoft on our test server (minus the one that is struck through - IE8 isn't installed, and the IE patch didn't seem to get installed) and upon reboot, none of the IIS application pools would stay started. We uninstalled the updates, and IIS worked again - this same behavior was seen on three different test servers.

I haven't been able to locate any other documentation where people have had this problem.

Does anyone know of this problem occurring for other people, and if there is a workaround that will allow IIS to function after installing the security updates?

(below copied from http://www.myitforum.com/forums/m_211648/mpage_1/key_/tm.htm#211648)

> Critical:
>   MS09-071: Vulnerabilities in Internet
>   Authentication Service Could Allow
>   Remote Code Execution (974318)
>   Affects: Windows 2000/XP (inc
>   x64)/2003 Server (inc x64)/Vista (inc
>   x64)/Server 2008 (inc x64) Link:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/MS09-071.mspx
>
> <strike>MS09-072: Cumulative Security Update
>   for Internet Explorer (976325)
>   Affects: Internet Explorer 6, 7 & 8
>   Link:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/MS09-072.mspx</strike>
>
> MS09-074: Vulnerability in Microsoft
>   Office Project Could Allow Remote Code
>   Execution (967183) Affects: Project
>   2000/2002/2003 Link:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/MS09-074.mspx
>
> Important:
>
> MS09-069: Vulnerability in Local
>   Security Authority Subsystem Service
>   Could Allow Denial of Service (974392)
>   Affects: Windows 2000/XP (inc
>   x64)/Server 2003 (inc x64) Link:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/MS09-069.mspx
>
> MS09-070: Vulnerabilities in Active
>   Directory Federation Services Could
>   Allow Remote Code Execution (971726)
>   Affects: Windows 2003 Server (inc
>   x64)/2008 Server (inc x64) Link:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/MS09-070.mspx
>
> MS09-073: Vulnerability in WordPad and
>   Office Text Converters Could Allow
>   Remote Code Execution (975539)
>   Affects: Windows 2000/XP (inc
>   x64)/Server 2003 (inc x64)/Office
>   XP/Office 2003/Works 8.5/Office
>   Converter Pack Link:
>   http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/MS09-073.mspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2009746